# Аналог 2gis по функционалу

Tags: php, html, карты

В больших городах удобно использовать 2gis, чтобы элементарно узнать расписание, для маленьких городов такого не существует. Подскажите варианты создания подобного сервиса, чтобы была карта, может даже использовать yandex/google или создать как то свою, чтобы при нажатии на объект из базы подгружались данные. Сам хорошо владею PHP (Yii2), HTML, CSS, JQ. Но не представляю каким образом реализовать карту.

P.S. Основной функцией является следующее: клик по зданию -> из моей базы загрузились все организации, по каждой также можно кликнуть, узнать номер/расписание и т.п.

Comment: OpenStreetMap, инструментов для неё навалом, возможно найдёте что-то подходящее для себя

Comment: «Клик по зданию» есть в Яндексе, его API позволяет узнавать адрес по координате

Comment: да, это понятно, интересует именно интерфейс, возможность подгружать и отображать организации, информации по ним, не просто Балун от яндекса, а полноценный информационный блок, как в 2Гис

Comment: в гугл картах это уже реализовано
https://www.google.ru/maps/place/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2/@52.4469362,30.978507,13.75z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1z0KDQtdGB0YLQvtGA0LDQvdGL!3m4!1s0x0:0x219f77215916d294!8m2!3d52.4443051!4d30.9949422

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717904/%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-c%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83/866674#866674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использую Leaflet + (MapBox, OSM).

- `Leaflet` - API. Простой и легкий (к тому же автор отечественный - Владимир Агафонкин).
- `MapBox` - Сервер отрендереных слоев, и редактор. Очень мощный инструмент для работы со слоями.
- `OSM` - наиболее полные данные, даже для моего небольшого города указано все, включая тропинки.

Comment: можно увидеть ссылку на проект?

Comment: Гугл не работает? А по сути, набивать свои данные по всей стране задача не подъёмная..

Comment: "Использую Leaflet + (MapBox, OSM)" на проект пользователя Максим гугл, к сожалению, не работает!
P.S. вся страна меня не интересует, мой город 35К

Comment: Не могу выложить ссылку тут ("хабраэфект" и прочие последствия). Но примеров и уроков по Leaflet в интернете достаточно.

Answer (score 3):

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/?lang=ru-RU
Вот через инструменты яндекса можешь через js(к сожалению через js тут все)
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/balloon_and_hint/ а вот тут все примеры и код можешь посмотреть даже начальные знания js помогут изменить по править по примерам.
Вот еще нашел кое что https://maps-creator.com/ может быть есть в ней польза для вас.

Comment: да, пользуюсь регулярно яндекс api  в своих проектах, думаю в эту же сторону, но ищу ещё альтернативы

Comment: увы как и писал andreymal его вариант и гугл еще возможны я смотрел аналог bing maps но там платная система( извиняюсь

Answer (score 1):

Принцип такой:
Пользуешься api понравившихся карт. С помощью его же ну и естественно js стилизуешь карту на свое усмотрение. Придется читать.

- По клику на нужные объект запускаешь функцию, которая возвращает
  данные о его координатах.
- Далее отправляешь ajax запрос на сервер, там устанавливаешь
  погрешность координат в пределах которых должны искаться данные в
  базе. (естественно данные об объекте должны быть в бд).
- Делаешь запрос к базе, где ищешь объект в пределах твоих координат.
- Отправляешь результат во вьюху, выводишь вьюху

другой вариант если есть подробные данные о фирмах и организациях. в каком то сервисе:

- По клику на нужные объект запускаешь функцию, которая возвращает
  данные о его координатах.
- Отправляешь координаты в сервис, получаешь результат