# как подключится к openstreetmap через API?

Tags: php, api, openstreetmap

как подключится к openstreetmap через API? я  реально не могу найти нормальной инфы. Мне надо подключится и поставить гео точки

```
<?

function get_saved_locations(){
    $con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", 'root', '','locations');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,"select lng,lat from locations ");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
        $rows[] = $r;

    }
    $indexed = array_map('array_values', $rows);

    //  $array = array_filter($indexed);

    echo json_encode($indexed);
    if (!$rows) {
        return null;
    }
}

?>

  <script>


var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [57.08231,25.24116],
  minZoom: 1.5,
  zoom: 7
})

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo( map )

var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="leaf-demo.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'leaf-demo.js', '' )

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + 'images/pin24.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: myURL + 'images/pin48.png',
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14]
})

for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; ++i ){
L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
.addTo( map );
</script>
```

Это всё работает , но это вывод для JSON, а мне надо из базы данных MYSQL, там всего 2 колонки lat lng

```
<?
   $con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", 'root', '','locations');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // update location with location_status if admin location_status.
    $sqldata = mysqli_query($con,"select lng,lat from locations ");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) {
        $rows[] = $r;

    }

?>
var tempArray = JSON.parse("[<?echo $r?>]");
```

Comment: Вы сегодня задавали похожий вопрос и я Вам привел ссылку, где я поверхностно сравнил несколько картографических движков, пример почти для всех берет тайлы openstreetmap. сам по себе osm это не движок, это информация (тайлы)

Answer (score 3):

OSM это не движок, это данные(тайлы).

Используйте например [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com), это карты 2д, с достаточно простым API, вот пример OSM:

```js
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18
});
var pt = new L.LatLng(60, 30.3);
var map = new L.Map('map', {
    center: pt,
    zoom: 12,
    layers: [osmLayer]
});
L.marker(pt).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('Кто тут ??')
.openPopup();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#map {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[другой мой пост с поверхностным сравнением разных Web карт и глобусов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717904/%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-c%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83/866674#866674)

Comment: изменил  описание вопроса наверху ... можете помочь с этим?

Comment: очень жалко((((

Comment: да, это я и хотел бы , но я не знаю как в javascrip-е заюзать этот массив из php..просто впервые сталкиваюсь , так как новенький в этом деле.

Comment: за вывод отвечает этот цикл фор в js и я не знаю как туда результат того запроса поставить ...или я чего то недопонимаю. я не знаю(

Comment: вот так выведите в лог http://php.net/manual/ru/debugger.php

Comment: зачем мне выводить  в лог , если я хочу вывести эти точки на карту ? )

Comment: чтобы мы могли увидеть что у Вас там =)

Comment: [["24.087828","56.925480"]]
вот что вывело .там всего лишь одна запись

Comment: присвойте это в var array = ... , а маркер создайте  L.marker(array[0]).addTo(map);

Comment: легко сказать))

Comment: var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode(get_saved_locations()); ?>;
L.marker( [tempArray[0].lat, tempArray[0].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
  .addTo( map );
вот так сделал , но чет не то

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d66bdf0368e88bb858f709cef59f503974039e5c

Comment: точку все равно не показывает (

Comment: @СаскеУчиха https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/LadaBE

Comment: а если в дб будет не одна запись , то тогда такая передача не пойдет  var tempArray = JSON.parse("[[60,30]]");
надо будет передать весь массив функции php(get_saved_locations())

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/232b1d97de2cf84269128724d54ddfca1afd6502

Comment: обновил там описание. он теперь тупо рандом место ставит точку и не меняет ее расположения. я тупо хочу чтоб он получил этот массив)))))))) заполнять вручную я и так могу ))) [] [] [] [] [] [] но чет не охото это делать:D

Comment: Карта получилась с первого раза, а где можно про АПИ почитать? Мне нужна ф-ция рисующую линию по двум координатам.

Comment: @nick_n_a вот например https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/