# Работа с картами и GPS на сайте

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, gps

Есть сайт написанный на ASP.NET MVC. Стоит задача ввести работу с картами и точками на сайте и GPS.
Функционал карт следующий:
1. Отобразить карту с точками на карте
2. Возможность щелкнуть на нужное место, добавить точку
3. Переместить точку
Функционал GPS:
Сайт будет работать на Андроиде, есть ли возможность с сайта обратиться к GPS устройства и взять координаты?
Подскажите возможные библиотеки, фрэймворки...которые можно использовать в технологии ASp net mvc ???

Comment: Asp это серверная технология, здесь же речь идёт о картах, это будет простыня JavaScript которую Вам просто надо будет добавить к ресурсам

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717904/188366

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.

Comment: нет проблем,  обращайтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам и написали в комментариях, отрисовка карты и работа с ней - дело клиента.

Я бы порекомендовал для работы с картами использовать библиотеку [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/).
На мобильных устройствах работает так же хорошо, как и на десктопах.

По поводу данных о местонахождении устройства (GPS):
используйте соответствующий api, все тот же javascript (если пользователь даст разрешение)
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пока остановился заказчик на Google Maps