# добавить панель (pane) (или полигон) на карте Leaflet

Tags: javascript, map, leafletjs

есть карта сделанная на leaflet, выглядит она вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Задача состоит в том, чтобы выделить определенную область на карте, например, всю Россию, под "выделить", имеется ввиду наложить слой (Pane) какого-то определенного цвета на всю страну (или регион, не суть важно). Вот пример, того что надо сделать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 **Как сделать выделение региона на карте leafletjs?** 
*P.S. Не обращайте внимания, что темы карт разные, пример приведен чтобы показать, как должно выглядеть выделение.*

Хочу дополнить, пускай это и не вопрос. Но самый легки способ получить полигон в  geoJSON, на мой взгляд, оказался вот такой:
`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q={COUNTRY}&polygon_geojson=1&format={FORMAT}` 
Вместо `{COUNTRY}` подставить название региона или страны, а вместо `{FORMAT}` подставить формат данных. В моем случает ссылка была такой:
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Russia&polygon_geojson=1&format=geojson

Comment: может быть Вам будет это интересно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717904/%D0%A1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-c%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь возможностью отображать [GeoJson](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let map = new L.Map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(60, 110),
  zoom: 2,
  layers: new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
});

let settings = {
  fillColor: "#e00",
  color: "#f00",
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.2
}

fetch("https://raw.githack.com/mapbox/tile-cover/master/test/fixtures/russia.geojson")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    L.geoJSON(json, settings).addTo(map);
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: а как поменять цвет выделения? Мне допустим, нужен красный с альфа каналом

Comment: @nosferatu-id подкорректировал ответ

Comment: ну и последнее, чтоб не пришлось искать потом, где можно получить .json других стран и регионов?

Comment: @nosferatu-id я искал в интернете =) есть вот такой, но он не разрезан по антимеридиану... https://github.com/d3/d3.github.com/blob/master/world-110m.v1.json