# Бесплатные карты

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, карты, geocode

Требуется вывести Город, Страна в левом верхнем углу сайта. Для этого пользовался объектом `navigator` и его методом `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)` , объектом `geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();` и его методом `geocode`. Возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю если я использую эти объекты в коде, то я должен подключить `Google Maps API`? Но в таком случае подключение этой библиотеки как написано в интернете платно.
2. Какие есть бесплатные карты? (вернее мне нужны только Город/Страна)

И как подключить автоматическое определение местоположения в выбранной библиотеке?

Comment: OpenStreetMap .

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717904/%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-c%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5/866674#866674

Comment: недавно было похожее задание, покапался и нашел для себя `LeafletJS`, отличная библиотека на `js`, рекомендую воспользоваться ей

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопрос то вроде о том, чтобы страну и город пользователя определить, а не карты найти.

Comment: геокодирование, как прямое так и обратное это конечно же чей-то сервис, моя ссылка для "возможной" помощи в поиске бесплатных карт, вроде это есть в вопросе